# Sequence contains no elements?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently using a single query in two places to get a row from a database.

```
BlogPost post = (from p in dc.BlogPosts
                 where p.BlogPostID == ID
                 select p).Single();
```

The query is fine when retrieving the row to put data in to the text boxes, but it returns an error "Sequence contains no elements" when used to retrieve the row in order to edit it and put it back in to the database. I can't understand why it might find an appropriate row in one instance but not another.

(Using ASP.NET MVC and LINQ)

Comment: you have to use SingleOrDefault , it will return null if no items returned

Comment: the error is saying it can not find any items in dc.BlogPosts which match the value of ID. Either ID has no value or the items in your list contain that item. Use SingleOrDefault or FirstOrDefault, these will return a null object if no item if found rather than error.

Comment: The question here is not to explain the meaning of "Sequence contains no elements", as many apparently think, but why it occurs. That question can't be answered because it lacks details.

Answer (score 518):

From "[Fixing LINQ Error: Sequence contains no elements](https://blogs.msmvps.com/kevinmcneish/2009/12/17/fixing-linq-error-sequence-contains-no-elements/)":

> When you get the LINQ error "Sequence contains no elements", this is usually because you are using the `First()` or `Single()` command rather than `FirstOrDefault()` and `SingleOrDefault()`.

This can also be caused by the following commands:

- `FirstAsync()`
- `SingleAsync()`
- `Last()`
- `LastAsync()`
- `Max()`
- `Min()`
- `Average()`
- `Aggregate()`

Comment: Perfect! 
`ctx.Rosters.First(c => c.RosterAccess == accCode);` <-- broken
`ctx.Rosters.FirstOrDefault(c => c.RosterAccess == accCode);` <-- WORKED

Comment: In my case I was doing a `Max` over an empty sequence

Comment: So now we know that each up vote weighs (at the moment) 31.25 pounds.

Comment: same for the Count()

Comment: broken link now

Comment: var callLog = db.CallLogs.First(x => x.MemberID == txtMemberId.Text);--> BROKEN                                                                                              var callLog = (from r in db.CallLogs
                                   where r.MemberID == txtMemberId.Text
                                   select r).FirstOrDefault(); --> WORKED

Comment: Are you sure that `LastOrDefault()` can also trigger that error ? Why ? I thought the "OrDefault" was all the point

Comment: Sometimes it's better to use Single() or First() without the Default, IF you are not expecting the collection to ever be empty. Otherwise bugs can go unnoticed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm!

Comment: Although this did fix my "Sequence contains no elements" error, now I am getting a NullReferenceException. ???

Answer (score 37):

Please use

```
.FirstOrDefault()
```

because if in the first row of the result there is no info this instruction goes to the default info.

Comment: In case of async call use .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Answer (score 16):

In addition to everything else that has been said, you can call `DefaultIfEmpty()` before you call `Single()`. This will ensure that your sequence contains something and thereby averts the InvalidOperationException "Sequence contains no elements". For example:

```
BlogPost post = (from p in dc.BlogPosts
                 where p.BlogPostID == ID
                 select p).DefaultIfEmpty().Single();
```

Answer (score 13):

Well, what is `ID` here? In particular, is it a local variable? There are some scope / capture issues, which mean that it may be desirable to use a second variable copy, just for the query:

```
var id = ID;
BlogPost post = (from p in dc.BlogPosts
                 where p.BlogPostID == id
                 select p).Single();
```

Also; if this is LINQ-to-SQL, then in the current version you get a slightly better behaviour if you use the form:

```
var id = ID;
BlogPost post = dc.BlogPosts.Single(p => p.BlogPostID == id);
```

Comment: ID is a GUID passed in as an argument

Answer (score 10):

This will solve the problem,

```
var blogPosts = (from p in dc.BlogPosts
             where p.BlogPostID == ID
             select p);
if(blogPosts.Any())
{
  var post = blogPosts.Single();
}
```

Comment: Hello , how can I solve error sequence contains no elements in my case if it is empty , can you check my case please this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69621734/why-i-got-this-error-sequence-contains-no-elements/69621906#69621906

Comment: This will run the query twice on the database and there could then be a race condition. It's better to use `SingleOrDefault()` and then check for `null`.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar situation on a function that calculates the average.

Example:

```
ws.Cells[lastRow, startingmonths].Value = lstMediaValues.Average();
```

Case Solved:

```
ws.Cells[lastRow, startingmonths].Value = lstMediaValues.Count == 0 ? 0 : lstMediaValues.Average();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Reason for error:**

1. The query `from p in dc.BlogPosts where p.BlogPostID == ID  select p` returns a sequence.
2. `Single()` tries to retrieve an element from the sequence returned in step1.
3. **As per the exception** - The sequence returned in step1 contains no elements.
4. Single() tries to retrieve an element from the sequence returned in step1 which contains no elements.
5. Since `Single()` is not able to fetch a single element from the sequence returned in step1, it throws an error.

**Fix:**

Make sure the query `(from p in dc.BlogPosts where p.BlogPostID == ID select p)`

returns a sequence with at least one element.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
......
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Column)
.Select(x => x.Column)
.Cast<DateTime?>()
.FirstOrDefault();
```

instead of simple `.Max()`. Then it returns pretty decent `null` when no rows. Without casting it returns the default datetime which usually makes no sense.