# Update database with passing values in entity framework database first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have Register Model in Db the below post method in controller does the update to database . However I also want to update Login data model

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(StudentDetail details)
        {
                if (DbAccess.LoginDetails.FirstOrDefault(student => student.Username == details.Username) == null)
                {
                    DbAccess.StudentDetails.Add(details);
                    **//here i also want to update login table with added details in database**
                    DbAccess.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("HomePage");
                }
                   return View();

        }
```

Below are the models created by entity framework db first

```
public StudentDetail()
        {

            this.UserFriends = new HashSet<UserFriend>();
        }

        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string UnivName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserFriend> UserFriends { get; set; }
    }

public partial class LoginDetail
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Can you guys suggest me the call to update LoginDetail table also with the Username and Password in that post method.

thanks,

Michaeld

Comment: How is `LoginDetail` related to a `StudentDetail`? Does `LoginDetail` have a `StudentDetailId`? Or `StudentDetail` have a `LoginDetailId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update and existing `LoginDetail` record:

```
var loginDetail = DbAccess.LoginDetails.Single(x => x.Username == details.Username);
loginDetail.Username = details.Username;
loginDetail.Password = details.Password;
DbAccess.Entry(loginDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
DbAccess.SaveChanges();
```

To add a new `LoginDetail` record:

```
var loginDetail = new LoginDetail{
Username = details.Username,
Password = details.Password
};
DbAccess.LoginDetails.Add(loginDetail);
DbAccess.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Sofanatic, I am not sure what the above code does so i copy pasted the above piece it throwed the error  "Sequence contains no elements" for the first line. however there are some data in LoginDetails

Comment: StackTrace = "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult...

Comment: (x => x.Username == details.Username);  I Dont understand this part    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907963/linq-query-issue-sequence-contains-no-elements       i found this but didn't help me out answered by adrian

Comment: this is assuming that a record for `LoginDetails` with a `Username` equal to `details.Username` already exists. If this is the first time it's being created then you should do the following. See answer for edit.