# Entity Framework datetime vs SQL Server date

Tags: entity-framework, date, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3. In my SQL Server 2008 db, I have some dates stored as dates rather than datetime.

I need to retrieve data using the date field, here a test code sample:

```
    public static Applicant Create()
    {   
        var dt = new DateTime(1967, 08, 03);

        var r = new CrudRepo<Applicant>(UowHelper.GetUow().Context);

        return r.Find(a => a.DateOfBirth == dt).Single();
    }
```

However, I'm getting an issue with 'missing sequence'.

Any ideas as to how I get around this?

I'll also need to update the database too at some point.

Thanks.

Comment: On which line do get the error? have you stepped into the crudrepo code?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324199/sequence-contains-no-elements

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what 'missing sequence' is? Is it 'Sequence contains no elements'? If this is the case then it is because `.Find` did not find any element. What is the `.Find` method and the `r` btw?

Comment: @Pawel - please see comments for spajce lower down. Basically when I try the match using linq I get no match - when I return the row then test a.DateOfBirth against dt - it works!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual result of `var dt = new DateTime(1967, 08, 03);` is `8/3/1967 12:00:00 AM`

The `DataType` of the `DateOfBirth` is `Date` so we need to TruncateTime the time.

msdn: [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395355.aspx)

```
public static Applicant Create()
    {   
        var dt = new DateTime(1967, 08, 03);

        var r = new CrudRepo<Applicant>(UowHelper.GetUow().Context);

        return r.FirstOrDefault(a => a.DateOfBirth == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(dt));
    }
```

or remove the `.Single() method` instead use the [.FirstOrDefault() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx)

Comment: Made the change but still getting the same issue - I've posted the error above. Find is a custom method that returns Iqueryable, so single() required.

Comment: try to replace `.Find()` to `.FirstOrDefault()` i updated my answer

Comment: dt = a.DateOfBirth - I've just tested, so I must be doing something dopey!

Comment: ok here's the weird thing. If I try to select using a.DateOfBirth = dt, then nothing is returned. If I return the row using another variable, then test against a.DateOfBirth against dt, it works!! Odd!!

Comment: Got it! I saud it would be something dopey - well it is, sort of. When creating the DateTime variable dt - I got the month/year the wrong way round, however when I output dt and a.DateOfBirth, both came out in the format I wanted to see 08/03/1967, hence I didnt notice that dt was actually 03/08/1967. Your truncate function worked for me after this was corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, to add to spajce's answer,

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityFunctions
```

has been deprecated to

```
System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions
```