# Finding the minimal difference after filtering item result in `Sequence contains no elements`

Tags: c#, linq

Those are my classes:

```
List<MyDate> Dates

public class MyDate
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public List<Tuple<DateTime, List<MyEnum>>> ToDates { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the nearest `FromDate` property to a `originDate`, but I need it to do the comparison only for items that answer the statement of `Where(d => d.ToDates.Any(t => t.Item2.Contains(MyEnum.Value1)))`

```
long nearestDiff = myList
            .Where(d => d.ToDates.Any(t => t.Item2.Contains(MyEnum.Value1)))
            .Select(d => d.FromDate)
            .Min(date => Math.Abs((date - originDate).Ticks));
```

The problem is when none of the items is answering the `Where` statement the `Select` statement throw the exception of:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'

I tried using the `SingleOrDefault` as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386227/6844481) suggested, but I need the Min value will be calculated against all values not only a single one.

Comment: I doubt Select is throwing this exception. What makes you believe it is Select which throws? Have you checked the stacktrace of the exception? Also, what precisely is `myList` (what type)?

Comment: `Select` isn't throwing the exception, `Min` is.  And the answer to which you linked **does not** suggest that you use `SingleOrDefault` in place of `Min`.