# Return value true or false from stored procedure in SQL and use it in asp core3 with dapper

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, asp.net-core

I have this stored procedure to validate some information, I need if this stored procedure to find value then return true and if not find any things it return the false.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateSubscribeDiscountDate]
    (@StartDate datetimeoffset,
     @EndDate datetimeoffset)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        1
    FROM 
        [SubscribeDiscount] SD
    WHERE 
        SD.StartDate = @StartDate
        AND SD.EndDeate = @EndDate
END
```

I'm using that in an ASP.NET Core MVC app like this:

```
public async Task<OperationResult<bool>> ValidateSubscribeDiscount(DateTimeOffset? StartDate, DateTimeOffset? EndDate)
{
        using (var userConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                var validate = await userConnection.QueryAsync<bool>(
                    "ValidateSubscribeDiscountDate",
                    new { StartDate = StartDate, EndDate = EndDate }
                    );
                var response = validate.First();

                return OperationResult<bool>.BuildSuccessResult(vlaidate.First()); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return OperationResult<bool>.BuildFailure(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

but I get this error:

> Sequence contains no elements

What's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check this for more help https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386227/5829426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because you use First when the result of the query doesn't contains any record returned by the WHERE clause. First assumes that there is always something in your IEnumerable to return. You can change your Stored Procedure to always return a value and then check that value from your C# code

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateSubscribeDiscountDate]
 (
     @StartDate datetimeoffset,
     @EndDate datetimeoffset
 )
 AS    
 BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [SubscribeDiscount] SD
              WHERE SD.StartDate =@StartDate
              AND SD.EndDeate=@EndDate)
    SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
END

...


var vlaidate = await userConnection.QueryAsync<int>(
    "ValidateSubscribeDiscountDate",new 
    { StartDate = StartDate, EndDate = EndDate });
bool response = vlaidate.First() == 1 ? true : false;
```

But probably the best way is to use, instead of First, FirstOrDefault. With this method you get a null return if the query doesn't produce any result and you can easily test that condition.

```
var vlaidate = await userConnection.QueryAsync<int>(
    "ValidateSubscribeDiscountDate",new 
    { StartDate = StartDate, EndDate = EndDate });
bool response = vlaidate.FirstOrDefault() != null ? true : false;
```

or, as commented here below, even a simple call to Any will do.

```
bool response = vlaidate.Any();
```

Comment: And in the second suggestion, since you're not actually using the value returned by `FirstOrDefault()` you could simply say `bool response = vlaidate.Any()`

Comment: Or using a `case` expression and returning a `bit`: `select Cast( case when exists ( select 42 from SubscribeDiscount where StartDate = @StartDate and EndDate = @EndDate ) then 1 else 0 end as Bit ) as Valid;`. (Or is it _really_ `EndDeate`?)